# Force ConcurrentDictionary in a Singleton Registry to Collect Removed Items/Space

Tags: c#, memory-management, collections

I have the following class which is used in a WebApi AspNetCore application as a singleton instance to store `Strategy` objects (reference type). The class is

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to allow singleton access to a common thread safe registry of registered strategies.
/// </summary>
public class StrategyRegister : IStrategyRegister
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<long, Strategy> _registery;

    public StrategyRegister()
    {
        _registery = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, Strategy>();
    }

    public bool TryAdd(Strategy strategy)
    {
        if (_registery.ContainsKey(strategy.Id))
            throw new SystemException("The registry can never contain two identical strategy ids");
        return _registery.TryAdd(strategy.Id, strategy);
    }

    public bool TryRemove(long id)
    {
        if (!_registery.ContainsKey(id))
            return true;

        //GC.Collect();
        return _registery.TryRemove(id, out _);
    }

    public Strategy TryGet(long id)
    {
        if (_registery.ContainsKey(id))
            return _registery[id];
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Strategy> GetRegisteredStrategies()
    {
        return _registery.Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

The problem is, as the `ConcurrentDictionary` grows large and items are removed, they are not being collected by the GC. I confirm this by adding the crude and nasty line `GC.Collect()` after every removal. When this is done, memory does not grow... I could make this "smarter" (still crude), by adding a timer to force collection every n seconds, but is there a better way, or should I be doing something obvious here?

Comment: and you are sure that nothing else is using _strategies_ when you remove them?

Comment: Yes, 100%. Once they are removed, they are "dead to me".

Comment: Try the following: run the application, open the task manager and create a memory dump (it's in the right mouse button menu for the process - Details tab -> Create dump file)... let it run for some time... create another momory dump. Drag-n-drop both files into Visual Studio and check what is really eating your memory.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have the .dmp files. I have opened them in VS, but there is no _obvious_ information that might tell me the root cause.

Comment: In one of the views you can see object instance counts an the amount of the memory they require.

Comment: Or see this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019) on the right side of the picture there is a _menu_, I believe it's the _Debug managed memory_

Comment: Yes, got it. It is indeed the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: cool, at least we could confirm that ;-)

Comment: So I am thinking of merely collecting using some periodicity - timer perhaps. Thoughts?

Comment: mhmm, maybe the [`TryRemove` source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,4d3f2a076a068c2e,references) does not immediately removes values from the inner storage? The source code is not easy to understad  :\

Comment: I see they use a singly-linked list for storing entries and manipulate only indicies... maybe they are still linked until overwritten? But this is actually just my conspiracy theory.

Comment: GC.Collect does not necesseraly free all unused memory. It is optimized with generations. Try calling GC.Collect(3, GCCollectionMode.Forced) and see what happens

Comment: I have checked the source myself. Some strange stuff occurring... "TryRemove does not really remove an element. All it does is changing linked list pointers to skip never assigning the value of an array element to null. This prevent GC from collecting old evicted objects." [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866642/concurrentdictionary-doesnt-seem-to-mark-elements-for-gc-when-they-are-removed). Forced GC not really helping - just slowing the problem.

Comment: Did you try to not use `out _`  but an explicit variable which you later set to `null` or  if `Strategy` implementing `IDisposable` calling `Dispose()`?

Comment: I have, no difference.

Comment: Are there any eventhandlers involved ?

Comment: Perhaps the only solution is to create a new instance with the values of the current and clear the obsolete instance after lots of values have been removed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513433/does-net-4-5-1-concurrentdictionary-tryremove-method-release-allocated-memory

Comment: No EventHandlers.

Comment: @dfhwze your suggestion seems to work. I tested it with a netcore2.2 console (1mln strings) and checked the results before and after with dotMemory and the old one is completely released and the memory usage drops by the expected amount (I removed every other element - or copied every other).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks very much for your time guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513433/does-net-4-5-1-concurrentdictionary-tryremove-method-release-allocated-memory), collections are optimized for performance over memory management. So I'm afraid it is up to us, consumers of the .NET Framework, to implement memory management on collections that grow big and require lots of manipulations.

I would use a scheduled task to periodically make a new instance of the queue, with the values of the previous instance, and clearing the old instance.